# How to move value from JSON Object to JS array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to save certain JSON values to JS array.

```
var count = Object.keys(item.programme).length; // item is JSON file, count is 23
for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    var title = item.programme[i].title.de;
    console.log(typeof title); //string
    console.log(title);  // desired values, title when i
    listData = [];
    listData[i] = title;
}
console.log(listData); // [undefined, undefined,.....,title when i =22]
```

I would like to get array of values from title variable. I get desired value only in last field of array, rest is `undefined`.

Comment: You are resetting `listData = [];` on every iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is kind of trivial. You define `listData` in each iteration. Move it outside the loop:

```
var listData = [];
for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    ...
    listData[i] = title;
}
```